# Access to Favorites questions directly from header or right column

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks, information-display

I really love the Favorites questions feature but I feel like it's a little bit buried.

Two main reasons:

1. Two clicks to reach it (from homepage or tagged questions)
2. Too close to prefs tab (my damaged brain always takes 1 or 2 seconds to decide, prefs or favorites?)

Is it possible to give it more prestige or prominence by adding a link to Favorites on header\right column?

**EDIT:**
I have modified [this](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/66416) GM script to have direct access to favorites.

Comment: What do you mean "more shine"?

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, any explanation :)?

Comment: @system: downvote on meta simply means that people don't like your idea; nothing personal.

Comment: @Kop I know thanks, i was just curious; probably i'm the only one who likes that feature :).

Comment: @system: probably because favorite questions are not something you want to see every day, and they would be difficult to fit in the narrow right column.. And if put in the header they would eat up very important vertical space.

Comment: @Kop Uhm, a star in the header\rightcolumn  pointing to Favorites would fit everywhere imho.Greasemonkey is my way :).

Comment: Agree with systempuntpuntoout on wanting this feature (Don't have enough rep to upvote you)- Why not just a tab at the top?

Comment: +1 I was about to make this feature request and came across this one. A `*` near questions tab wouldn't hurt I believe. Till then I can just type `fav` into Firefox's address bar and it would give me http://stackoverflow.com/users/165297?tab=favorites#tab-top as first item.