# What about a recent favourites list in the right bar?

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access to Favorites questions directly from header or right column](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46021/access-to-favorites-questions-directly-from-header-or-right-column)

As a suggestion for the more casual user (often in an office), how's about a list of items that you have recently 'favourited' (horrible use of the word).  I often go past a question and add it to my favourites, intending to revisit it at some point later on in the day to see the answers, but regularly forget and never get around to it.

My suggestion would be another item in the right bar, around where the tags are that is a list of items that have been marked as favourite in the last few days - for me it'd be a bit like a simple 'todo' list - things I'm interested in.

Comment: Hmm, I appear to have sinned, and added a close duplicate to this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46021/access-to-favorites-questions-directly-from-header-or-right-column